# How to read all content by java Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This code is **wrong**:

```
String result = "";
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    result += scanner.nextLine() + System.lineSeparator();
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Because `nextLine()` cannot distinguish **a line separator**, or **an EOF (without an empty line)**.

So how to read exactly all content by Scanner?

Comment: That code is right. `hasNextLine` will return false when the scanner reaches EOF.

Comment: @Sweeper I tried use Mac java8, `hasNextLine` returns true when reaches EOF

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? I cannot reproduce this. Show the file from which you are reading too.

Comment: @Sweeper OP wants an _EXACT_ reproduction of the entire input. With the exact right newlines and all that. Scanner is being abused here, the real answer is that FredSuvn went wrong someplace well before they ever got to this question.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Oh I see. Is that what OP meant? Then they need `Files.readString` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Scanner isn't the right tool for the job. You had some input. You then wrapped that input in a scanner. And that was your mistake.

Had you not done that, this exercise (read it all into a giant string) would have been trivial.

We can butcher that scanner beyond all recognition and make it do something it wasn't designed to:

```
String example = "a\nb\r\nc\r\n";
scanner.useDelimiter("Well, this string certainly isn't in there!");
String result = scanner.next();
System.out.println(example.equals(result));
```

> `true`

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this, though. Scanner implies things like 'I want the exact line ending the original input had' don't matter anymore. If they do, don't use Scanner.

Comment: Your `useDelimiter` is so hack. you are right, `Scanner` is a wrong tool.